# Google Identity Toolkit returns INVALID_CREDENTIALS

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-identity-toolkit

I'm currently trying to implement a forgot password feature using the Google Identity Toolkit. The PHP backend is trying to get the oob code because client (iOS) does not have sufficient privileges.

Whenever I run the script I get an error of *INVALID_CREDENTIALS*, more specifically:

```
oob Code: string(249) "{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "message": "Invalid Credentials", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Invalid Credentials" } } "
```

I am not sure where to get the **authToken** or whether this is sending the post request correctly.

```
$authToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$email = $_POST['email'];
$uIp = $_POST['ip']; 
//Post Data in Array
$postData = array(
    'kind' => 'identitytoolkit#relyingparty',
    'requestType' => 'PASSWORD_RESET',
    'email' => '$email',
    'challenge' => 'verified',
    'captchaResp' => 'verified',
    'userIp' => '$uIp',
    'newEmail' => 'null',
    'idToken' => 'null'
    );

//Setup cURL
$ch = curl_init('https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getOobConfirmationCode?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: '.$authToken,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData)
));
//Send Request
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app) on the Google API PHP client shows you how to get an OAuth token for your app.

However, you will probably find it easier to use the Identity Toolkit specific [PHP client](https://github.com/google/identity-toolkit-php-client). To generate the forgot-password link, all you need to do is call the getOobResults() method on an initialized GitkitClient.

Comment: I'm still having a problem with this. I'm now calling the getOobResults method but I'm getting the error "{"response_body":{"error":"CAPTCHA_CHECK_FAILED"}}". Where am I supposed to get the challenge and response from the captcha? I am using a separate system to do this independently, is there some Google api I should be using? Thanks again for your help!